how to unbind Ctrl-R in Ubuntu with byobu tmux backend
My environment is as below.

Ubuntu 22.04
Gnome Terminal
Byoubu with tmux backend
bash with emacs command line editing

When I type Ctrl-r I am getting below error
tmux: unknown option -- B
usage: display-popup [-CE] [-c target-client] [-d start-directory] [-h height] [-t target-pane] [-w width] [-x position] [-y position] [command]

In my ~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux, I tried unbind -n C-R, but did not work.
Any idea on how I can configure this?
thanks

Having --tmux option in FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS for fzf was causing this issue.
